# Name of a fantasy/science fiction romance book about human female and humanoid lion

Tags: aliens, time-travel, story-identification

I am looking for a book where the female hero is kinda depressed about life. I think she recently had a breakup or so, so she was unhappy with the contemporary male species. She gave a weird Chinese cat doll I think a belly rub and is transported to the future. Once arriving there, she firstly finds herself captive of some kind of aliens and later on was found to not be a spy.

Earth is at war, I just cannot remember whether it was with some other country or some alien invader, or both. I do know that she is an empath and this is somehow supposed to help stop the war somehow. She falls in love with a humanoid lion alien and there is lots of kinky sex. Also, throughout the book the lion temporarily loses his memory of her because of his father, who is against their relationship.

I cannot exactly remember when I read the book, but it's been some years. I also know that it is several years old, so nothing new. Definitely 7 years or so. I also forgot whether or not it was part of a series or stand-alone novel. The cover I think has a lion head on it, and the title might be something about warriors of some weird sounded planet/alliance.

Comment: It would help greatly if you [edit]ed your question to add more details, e.g. when you read this book, where, and in what language. Of course, any additional plot points are welcome as well, as long as you add them to the question and not to comments.

Comment: There are some plot points in common with Lisanne Norman's Sholan series. Cat aliens, human empath. The first book is called Turning Point. I don't remember time travel though nor lots of kinky sex.

Answer (score -1):

This may be the book Down below station, if I remember the plot.

Comment: If you do remember the plot, then can you explain how this book matches the OP's description? It would also be helpful if you could list the author.

Comment: I assume you mean the hani from the [Chanur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chanur_novels) books by Cherryh, but don't believe they are in _Downbelow Station_.  Nor do I recall any romance in the Chanur books.

Comment: Definitely NOT "Downbelow Station." No time travelers.  No depressed chicks, no kinky sex with humanoid lions, no "empaths," no humanoid lions, no "weird Chinese cat doll." Nothing in common at all, except that both books were probably printed on paper.